# Accurately Calculate Harmonic Numbers for Values Between 1 and 10

Tags: c++, math, optimization, numeric

I've been working on a project in C++, and as part of the project I need to calculate harmonic numbers for real values. I have a pretty accurate formula to do it for values over 40, and using a Kahan sum I can accurately get the Harmonic Number of an integer, but I'm at a loss as to how to accurately calculate values like `HarmonicNumber(1.5)`. How can I do this?

Note: if anyone has fast c++ code for calculating the Digamma function I could also use that because the Digamma function is easy to transform into the HarmonicNumber function.

Edit: I've written the following code, although I'm hoping there's something faster and less cumbersome.

Edit 2: I need a relative error smaller than 10^-15 for double-precision values and smaller than 10^-18 for 80-bit extended-precision values like "long double"

```
long double HarmonicNumber(long double n)
{
//Absolute error is smaller than or equal to 2^-61, or 4.33681e-19, for n<5000
//For n>5000, all but the last two bits are correct. 
constexpr long double m1 = 1.0L / 24;
constexpr long double m2 = -7.0L / 960;
constexpr long double m3 = 31.0L / 8064;
constexpr long double m4 = -127.0L / 30720;
constexpr long double m5 = 511.0L / 67584;
constexpr long double m6 = -1414477.0L / 67092480;
constexpr long double m7 = 8191.0L / 98304;
constexpr long double EulerGamma = 0.5772156649015328606065120900824024310421L;
long double v = n + 0.5L;
long double v2 = 1.0L / (v * v);
//Uses asymptotic expansion with progressively more terms.
//Fewer terms are needed for larger inputs.
if(n >= 10000.L) return m1*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
if(n >= 450.00L) return (m2*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
if(n >= 110.00L) return ((m3*v2 + m2)*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
if(n >= 42.000L) return (((m4*v2 + m3)*v2 + m2)*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
if(n >= 24.000L) return ((((m5*v2 + m4)*v2 + m3)*v2 + m2)*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
if(n >= 17.000L) return (((((m6*v2 + m5)*v2 + m4)*v2 + m3)*v2 + m2)*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
if(n >= 13.000L) return ((((((m7*v2 + m6)*v2 + m5)*v2 + m4)*v2 + m3)*v2 + m2)*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
if(n >= 6.0L)
{
    //Calculates HarmonicNumber(n+7) and then subtracts fraction to find HarmonicNumber(n)
    v = n + 7.5L;
    v2 = 1.0L / (v * v);
    auto base = ((((((m7*v2 + m6)*v2 + m5)*v2 + m4)*v2 + m3)*v2 + m2)*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
    long double n2 = n + 4.0L;
    auto n2sq = n2*n2;
    auto n2sh = n2sq - 7.0L;
    auto shft = 1.0L / n2 + (2*n2*n2sh*(3.0L*n2sq-7.0L))/(n2sq*n2sh*n2sh-36.0L);
    return base - shft;
}
else
{
    //Calculates HarmonicNumber(n+14) and then subtracts fraction to find HarmonicNumber(n)
    v = n + 14.5L;
    v2 = 1.0L / (v * v);
    auto base = ((((((m7*v2 + m6)*v2 + m5)*v2 + m4)*v2 + m3)*v2 + m2)*v2 + m1)*v2 + log(v) + EulerGamma;
    long double n2 = n + 4.0L;
    auto n2sq = n2*n2;
    auto n2sh = n2sq - 7.0L;
    auto shft = 1.0L / n2 + (2*n2*n2sh*(3.0L*n2sq-7.0L))/(n2sq*n2sh*n2sh-36.0L);
    n2 = n + 11.0L;
    n2sq = n2*n2;
    n2sh = n2sq - 7.0L;
    shft += 1.0L / n2 + (2*n2*n2sh*(3.0L*n2sq-7.0L))/(n2sq*n2sh*n2sh-36.0L);
    return base - shft;
}
```

}`

Comment: Can you mention exactly how accurate your calculation needs to be? If the precision allows, you can brute force it by precomputing a lookup table and use approximations around them.

Comment: I want it to be as accurate as possible - preferably double precision at least. I looked at stitching together a bunch of polynomial interpolations, but that was cumbersome

Comment: Can you add the precision requirement to the question? It is difficult to answer without a defined requirement

Comment: I want the relative error to be less than 10^-18 for 80-bit "long doubles" and less than 10^-15 for regular doubles for inputs greater than 1

Comment: Then add it to the **question**. It is important, to put it lightly

Answer (score 1):

Usually the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) function is understood as being defined only for integers. As you point out, you can use the relation H_{n} = \psi(n+1) + \gamma to convert to the [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) function, which is defined for non-integers. You might call this generalizing the harmonic number function to non-integers, but if you don't want the mathematical people you talk to to scratch their heads and look at you cross-ways, you'd be better off just saying you want to compute the digamma function.

So you want to compute the digamma function for small as well as large values. Fortunately, [Wikipedia tells you how](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_and_approximation). I'll just summarize here. For large x, you want to use the asymptotic expansion in terms of Bernoulli numbers.

[image: Psi asymptotic expansion]

You can get full double precision with a stored table of the first dozen Bernoulli numbers for all x >~ 16. For smaller x, just use

[image: Psi shift]

to move x out to a large enough value to apply the first technique. For example, for x = 12.5, just do the sum s = 1/12.5 + 1/13.5 + 1/14.5 + 1/15.5. Then compute \psi(16.5) via the previous technique and subtract s to get \psi(12.5).

In my own [library](https://github.com/dcwuser/metanumerics/), I use a more complicated technique for small x that is a little faster and a little less subject to cancellation error, but the difference is pretty small. This simple technique is good enough for most purposes.

Finally, for negative arguments, and for arguments very close to zero, you should use the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula)

[image: Psi reflection]

to transform to a positive argument.

Putting all this together, you get the following code:

```
static const int bernoulli_length = 8;
static const double bernoulli[] = {
    1.0 / 6.0, -1.0 / 30.0, 1.0 / 42.0, -1.0 / 30.0,
    5.0 / 66.0, -691.0 / 2730.0, 7.0 / 6.0, -3617.0 / 510.0
};

double Psi(double x) {

    // Reflect to positive x
    if (x < 0.25) {
        // For x very close to a negative integer, this will loose accuracy
        // due to finite PI. To fix this, we need sinpi and cospi functions. 
        return (Psi(1.0 - x) - M_PI * cos(M_PI * x) / sin(M_PI * x));
    }

    // Shift out to large enough x
    double s = 0.0;
    while (x < 16.0) {
        s += 1.0 / x;
        x += 1.0;
    }

    // Use the asymptotic expansion
    double psi = log(x) - 1.0 / (2.0 * x);
    double x2 = x * x;
    double x2k = 1.0;
    for (int k = 0; k < bernoulli_length; k++) {
        double psi_old = psi;
        x2k *= x2;
        psi -= bernoulli[k] / (2 * (k + 1) * x2k);
        if (psi == psi_old) {
            return(psi - s);
        }
    }
    throw std::range_error("Convergence failure.");
}
```

I would say this is a bit clearer.

Comment: Please, note that, unlike other SE sites, MathJax isn't supported here, on Stack Overflow. You may want to convert your formulas to images.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'd already read through the wikipedia articles for both Harmonic Numbers and the Digamma function, and there are a number of ways to generalize harmonic numbers to the real numbers. My above code actually does rely on an asymptotic expansion, just not precisely the Bernoulli expansion, and for values of x smaller than 14 I do actually convert it into a value of x larger than 14 using the identity you described - it's just that I compress that step into one block that allows me to shift it by 7 instead of 1. My code is accurate, just... ugly.

Comment: @Jorge: I've added my code for this approach, which I think is less cumbersome and ugly.